# React: incorrect examples of calling Hooks inside loops and nested functions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The first rule of Hooks is to only call hooks at the top level, i.e. "Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions". The docs [explains pretty clearly with an example for calling Hooks inside conditions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation), but not for the other two cases: loops and nested functions.

**Are there examples where something can go wrong when calling Hooks inside loops and nested functions? Moreover, isn't a custom hook just a nested function?**

The provided answers for these two related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53906843/2013891) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55215333/2013891) unfortunately only give the correct examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example of variable-length loop:

```js
const {useState} = React

const WrongLoop = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const [x, setX] = useState(i)
  }
  const [unknownOrder, setUnknownOrder] = useState('some state')
  
  return <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c+ 1)}>{count} {unknownOrder}</button>
}

ReactDOM.render(<WrongLoop />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Example of nested function that would be hard to detect by eslint (custom hooks are a special case - when using the `use...` prefix in function name, it's usage in the component can be statically analyzed by eslint):

```js
const {useState} = React

const fn = () => {
  const [x, setX] = useState() // is it OK to use hooks unconditionally here?
}

const WrongFn = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
  if (count === 1) {
    fn() // OK to use normal functions conditionally.. but what if there's a hook inside?
  }
  const [unknownOrder, setUnknownOrder] = useState('some state')
  
  return <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c+ 1)}>{count} {unknownOrder}</button>
}

ReactDOM.render(<WrongFn />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples! :) But don't you think the nested function example would also be easily caught by ESLint because it violates rule #2 ([Only Call Hooks from React Functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions))?

Comment: both examples are caught by ESLint rules, not sure what is your point... you were asking `isn't a custom hook just a nested function?` and I tried to illustrate that no, it isn't, because for a custom hook, the ESLint rule would be able to detect usage of a custom hook inside `if`. but for a regular function, it's OK to use a regular function inside `if`, so they had to make it NOT OK to use a hook inside a regular function

Comment: Gotcha. My point is the two rules (for the "nested functions" part) boil down to: **Don’t call Hooks inside nested functions unless the nested functions are either React function components or custom Hooks.** Correct? Anyway, I'm already satisfied your answer, so thanks again!